# How do I resize a drawable programmatically using picasso for use in a notification action icon

Tags: android, notifications, icons, picasso

I like the ease of use of picassos resize thingy as shown:

```
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(finalImgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(linearLayout1.getWidth(), linearLayout1.getWidth()).into(image);
```

but how do I do that to an image inside my drawable folder for an icon on an action in the notification? Is it possible to do it without using target? I have multipe .addAction lines so how would it know which one to put it in? Something like the bottom one, what do I put into into()??

```
            .addAction(Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_directions_black_36dp).resize(36, 36).into(?????), "Map", piMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso supports loading images from other sources like: Resources, assets, files, content and providers ([Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)). With that knowledge this can load an image 
from a drawable folder

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.image).resize(50,50).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Note: getActivity is the context here because I have tried it in a fragment. The rest can apply too.
Please refer to the above link for more details